# How to list all tables with Azure.Data.Tables?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I used to be able to list all tables (Table Storage) using `tableClient.ListTablesSegmentedAsync();` with package `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`

However since it is deprecated and I want to use the recommended package `Azure.Data.Tables` I am missing the functionality to list all tables.

How is this achieveable now?

Comment: mark if the answer helped

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables#get-an-azure-table)

```
/ Use the <see cref="TableServiceClient"> to query the service. Passing in OData filter strings is optional.

Pageable<TableItem> queryTableResults = serviceClient.Query(filter: $"TableName eq '{tableName}'");

Console.WriteLine("The following are the names of the tables in the query results:");

// Iterate the <see cref="Pageable"> in order to access queried tables.

foreach (TableItem table in queryTableResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(table.Name);
}
```

Comment: If using this method: can I access the entity of the said TableItem? Because the method .DeleteEntity() is not accessible from here. Is there a workaround?

Comment: no you need to use TableClient for that